# How to change multiple databases with dacpac file help of Azure DevOps (CD /CI Process)

Tags: c#, azure-devops, build, azure-sql-database, dacpac

I am tiring to changes multiple Databases with single DACPAC file. all Databases schema are same.

On every PR the DacPac file changes is made. Now on the changes that made on dacpac file is to reflect on multiple database.

**Note : Only Template DB has available VS Code changes push to in Azure CD/CI Pipeline. Release is success in Template DB, it should applicable for all Tenant DBs.**

Guys could you provide any solution using Azuer DevOPs CD/CI Pipeline.

Comment: I think you could use this task: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/README.md

Answer (score 1):

**Note :** Import operation cannot be performed on existing databases. Yes, you can perform an Import operation to multiple databases using single .dacpac file, but if you want to initiate the second import operation that will create a new database or new databases as in your scenario.

Configure you build pipeline in Azure Devops, to generate the dacpac file, add Visual Studio build task. Some required fields are needed to be filled.

[image]

In order to publish dacpac file, it needs to be copied to artifact staging directory. To do that add Copy files task. Choose folder where dacpac file gets generated after build for Source Folder field. Enter your dacpac file name with file extension in Content field. Enter $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in Target Folder field. The value used for the last field is predefined variable for Azure Pipelines and it gives artifact location where Publish Artifact task is going to be used later on.

[image]

Next task, publish dacpac file and publish profile as build artifact. This will be used for release pipeline. To make that, add Publish build artifacts task. Enter $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) in Path to publish field

[image]

Next, integrate it with the release pipeline. To set the artifact, click on Add button in the artifacts box, choose Build as the source type, fill the required fields then click Add.

[image]

**Here, for your scenario**

**1.** Setup multiple release pipelines (which will have same artifacts from single build pipeline )
Select artifact and enable continues deployment trigger (Set no filter on branch )

[image]

Now, when you do a new build, automatically both release will start.

**Alternately if you are looking to update multiple databases as in different environments, you can**

**2.** Using Branch Filters on the Build and Artifact Filters on the Release will help you manage this scenario with just one build and one release.

Since you kept the same database schema, once done you can simply change your pipeline and allow them both to be updated from the same source i.e one build pipeline with many branch filters.

Now go to the triggers tab on your build, and enable continuous integration. Branch filters will appear. Here for example you can add say both develop and master, so that this build is triggered from either branch.

[image]

With this completed the build will be triggered when you commit to either of these branches.

Next, in the release pipeline set an Artifact filter for each environment or database, now the release is triggered for each branch! no need for multiple builds and releases for the same product.

For example you can tell the Production Stage that only a build from the master branch can trigger the production stage.